# Undefined variable not allowing me to insert file into database table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm uploading audio files into a directory and storing the file name info in database. I have done this successfully.

Next I wanted to create a default image for each audio file, by use PHP to add the audio files Title to the image and then tack on a unique id to the file name. I have done this successfully. I learned this by [following this tutorial.](http://papermashup.com/php-gd-generate-an-image-with-text-and-font-embedding/)

Example Image:

[image]

The problem I'm having is getting the audio files image to insert into the database column on upload.
Here is a database image. I need the file name of the newly created audio image to go into the **rt_file** column. So I can echo it out later.

[image]

I was hoping to get some help on where I'm going wrong.

The current error I get is: **Undefined variable: rt_file**.
Which I don't understand why...? does this not define it like I have it defined above the insert statement like this:

```
$rt_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', "../ringtones/rtimage/".($ringtone_image[0]['ring_name'])."-".substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5).".jpg");
```

I really hate to post this much code I know it's frowned upon, so I apologize in advance, but I'm not sure where the problem lies.

If someone has some time to look through this that would be great, if not I totally  understand.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/core/database.php");


$ringDir= "../ringtones/";

if(!is_dir($ringDir)){

    mkdir('../ringtones/', 0775);
}



.   
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {

            ?>
<div class="add-errors">Please add an audio file!</div>
<?php 

    }   else {

        $name       =   $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filename   =   preg_replace("/\.[^.]+$/", "", $name);
        $temp       =   $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $type       =   $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $size       =   $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $ext        =   strtolower(end(explode('.', $name)));

  $upload   =   substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);

        // Restrictions for uploading
        $allowed    =   array(
        'audio/mp3',
        'audio/mp4',
        'audio/mpeg',
        'audio/ogg',
        'audio/opus',
        'audio/webm');

        // Recognizing the extension
        switch($type){

            case 'audio/mp3':
                    $ext= '.mp3';
            break;

            case 'audio/mp4':
                    $ext= '.mp4';
            break;

            case 'audio/mpeg':
                    $ext= '.mpeg';
            break;

            case 'audio/ogg':
                    $ext= '.ogg';
            break;

            case 'audio/opus':
                    $ext= '.opus';
            break;

            case 'audio/webm':
                    $ext= '.webm';
            break;

        }

        // upload variables
        $ring_path      =   $ringDir.$filename."-".$upload.$ext;





        // check if extension is allowed.
        if (in_array($type, $allowed)) {

            // Checking the size of the audio file.
                if ($size <= 5242880) {

                        // Move the original file aswell.
                        move_uploaded_file($temp, $ring_path);



/*#############THIS IS WHERE I'M ADDING THE TEXT TO THE DEFAULT IMAGE###########
################################################################################*/

// link to the font file no the server
$fontname = '../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf';
// controls the spacing between text
$i=30;
//JPG image quality 0-100
$quality = 100;

function create_image($ringtone_image){

        global $fontname;   
        global $quality;
        $rt_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', "../ringtones/rtimage/".($ringtone_image[0]['ring_name'])."-".substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5).".jpg");  

     //if the file already exists dont create it again just serve up the original   
    if (!file_exists($rt_file)) {   
    }

            // define the base image that we lay our text on
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("../ringtones/ringtone-image.jpg");

            // setup the text colours
            $color['white'] = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

            // this defines the starting height for the text block
            $height = 50;
            $y = imagesy($im) - $height;

        // loop through the array and write the text    
        foreach ($ringtone_image as $value){
            // center the text in our image - returns the x value
            $x = center_text($value['ring_name'], $value['font-size']);

            imagettftext($im, $value['font-size'], 0, $x, $y, $color[$value['color']], $fontname,$value['ring_name']);
            // add 32px to the line height for the next text block
            //$i = $i+32;   

        }
            // create the image
            imagejpeg($im, $rt_file, $quality);

    //}

        return $rt_file;    
}

function center_text($string, $font_size){

            global $fontname;

            $image_width = 550;
            $dimensions = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $fontname, $string);

            return ceil(($image_width - $dimensions[4]) / 2);               
}



    $ringtone_image = array(

        array(
            'ring_name'=> 'Add Ringtone Title', 
            'font-size'=>'16',
            'color'=>'white'),

    );



    $ringtone_image = array(

        array(
            'ring_name'=> $_POST['ring_name'], 
            'font-size'=>'16',
            'color'=>'white'),


    );      



// run the script to create the image
$filename = create_image($ringtone_image);

/*#############END TEXT TO DEFAULT IMAGE###########
###################################################*/


                        try {

                            $ring_id            =   Input::get('ring_id');
                            $creation           =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $ring_name          =   Input::get('ring_name');
                            $category           =   Input::get('category_id');
                            $ring_path          =   $ring_path;
                            $rt_file            =   $rt_file;   


                            $insertdata = DB::getInstance()->insert('ringtones', array(
                                'ring_id'            => $ring_id,
                                'creation'           => $creation,
                                'ring_name'          => $ring_name,
                                'category_id'        => $category,
                                'ring_path'          => str_replace("../ringtones/", "", $ring_path),
                                'rt_file'           => str_replace("../ringtones/rtimages/", "", $rt_file),
                            ));


                            if(!$insertdata) {

                                ?>
<div class="add-errors">There was a problem uploading the ringtone!</div>
<?php 

                            } else {

                                ?>
<div class="add-message">Your ringtone has been uploaded! <a href="add-ringtone.php">Add another</a> or <a href="../index.php">Return Home</a> </div>
<?php 
                            }

                        } catch(Exception $e) {
                            ?>
<div class="add-errors">
        <?php die($e->getMessage()); ?>
</div>
<?php 
                        }

                } else {
                    ?>
<div class="add-errors">Your ringtone size is too big!</div>
<?php
                }

            }

         else {
            ?>
<div class="add-errors">Your have uploaded a forbidden extension!</div>
<?php

}

}

}

?>
<section>
        <h1>Audio Upload</h1>
        <p>Use the form below to upload new ringtone</p>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="ring_name">Ringtone Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="ring_name" maxlength="42" placeholder="Give this field a title">
                <label for="category_id">Choose a category</label>
                <select name="category_id">
                        <option value="">Please Choose</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
                        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
                        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
                </select>
                <label for="file">Ringtone</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" >
                <p id="size">Maximum file size of 5MB</p>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$rt_file = null; // here we're initiate the variable with null to avoid undefined var problem

function create_image($ringtone_image) {
    global $rt_file; // here we're accessing global variable to use it inside function
    // rest part
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of it?

Comment: I wrote the part where must be fixed. not the whole code.

Comment: @num8er I appreciate the help , but where is that supposed to go?

Comment: "The current error I get is: Undefined variable: rt_file. Which I don't understand why...? does this not define it like I have it defined above the insert statement like this:"

- because You've defined (instantiated) Your variable $rt_file inside of function (local scope), so in global scope this variable does not exist.

Comment: You've to agree that code You give is not brilliant, so I've wrote quick fix of Your problem.

Comment: @num8er Yes I agree not brilliant at all I really appreciate your help. One issue though is `function create_image($ringtone_image) use ($rt_file)` is throwing an error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Comment: @num8er That totally worked out great! Thanks so much for the help. I've been at this all day trying to figure that out and would have never thought of what you did. Thanks for explaining why the variable wasn't getting defined too.